# CSS HTML Problem, i can not see the ptcture by mozilla and expolrer

Tags: html, css

[image: photo number1: that is in mozilla fire fox and explore Browser]

[image: photo number 2: that is in google chrome Browser]

what is the reason, that I can not see the picture by mozilla and expolre
photo number1: that is in mozilla fire fox and explore Browser 
photo number 2: that is in google chrome Browser

```
<div style="display: inline-flex;" >
    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <ul>
                <th id="th">Managers
                </th>
                <th id="th">photo </th>
                <th id="th"> Favorite saying to motivate</th>

            </ul>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <ul>
                <td>Ali Alahmad</td>
                <td> <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/business-vol-2-flat-icons/72/57-512.png" width="100" height="100"></td>
                <td> A year from now you may wish you had started today</td>
            </ul>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <ol>
                <td>Mohamad Batan</td>
                <td> <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/n3clVffDASpg_SKsRgjBQIkaMyB4X66HthmC6VNHGr1QpOOq4BZA52op-PcAZWgqDvayYl8P6n-zeCbwslH4w5bLIy9LQjWic-MFDYEnHGQVIGRc_RY0AyeOUJI6hdX1e7EpBqFI2ggISHX7irwecA9NCIQhcA" width="100" height="100"></td>
                <td> Don't let the past hold you, you're missing the good stuff</td>
            </ol>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Khandro</td>
            <td> <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/user-23/512/User_Executive_1.png" width="100" height="100"> </td>
            <td>Every new day is another chance to change your life</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your URL simply is not valid.  It might be a private image you are able to see being logged into Chrome.

Comment: Your HTML is also invalid as ol can only contain li

Answer (score 1):

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/n3clVffDASpg_SKsRgjBQIkaMyB4X66HthmC6VNHGr1QpOOq4BZA52op-PcAZWgqDvayYl8P6n-zeCbwslH4w5bLIy9LQjWic-MFDYEnHGQVIGRc_RY0AyeOUJI6hdX1e7EpBqFI2ggISHX7irwecA9NCIQhcA
```

Looks like a link to a GMAIL proxy image, these can only be viewed if you're logged into gmail as the user that received the email with this image.

To clarify, when you send an email with an image to someone though gmail, google will download this image into their own cache server `googleusercontent` and then send that link instead of the original image.

This is to protect you from viruses or unauthorized downloads that may happen because the image may not actually be an image when it's sent by a malicious user.

What happens is that the google cached image can only be viewed by the person who was meant to receive it, and google knows this only if you're logged in as that user.

Try asking the person that can see it to download that image to his/her computer and sending it to you or uploading it again to some server.

Comment: I randomly searched over the internet for an image to use in my project. I don't know the one who got the email

Comment: And also from my mobile I can not see the photo

Comment: Right click and download the photo and then try to use your downloaded photo on that website

Comment: Also remember to respect the copyright of the photo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they can't load that one picture. Try to download it and put the Image Path in the img src

Answer (score 0):

You are logged in via Google on chrome that is why you can see it, but not in other browsers.

So it need the correct cookie stored to know that it's you that is requesting the file.

Comment: I unsubscribed from google chrome and still see the picture

Comment: Are you using any content blocker on the other browsers?

Comment: Also just download the image and re-upload to an image service or just show it locally/from server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems your link is wrong. I can't see the picture in any browser.
if you try the `url` picture in your browser directly you can see that it returns `403 Unauthorized` error from google. By and Large this picture is not public.

[Browser Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVTHC.png)

Comment: I still opened the link from explorer and mozilla, and I saw a 404 error like you. But I see the picture from Chrome. Even though I unsubscribed from chrome